# EclipseLink default value for columns that used in JoinColumns

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have this piece of code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOVERS")
public class MOVers implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "X1077_69_EDECESSOR", referencedColumnName = "CLASSID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "X1077_70_EDECESSOR", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private MOVers predecessor;
}
```

The database should not have null values. If created version is the first then it should not have predecessor, and columns (X1077_69_EDECESSOR, X1077_70_EDECESSOR) should be equal to 0. I thought about creation of Dummy object for this reason, but it is not possible because some other columns must be unique.

How can I do it by using EclipseLink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database have no any foreign keys, and this DB is used in other application with persistence API that do not understand NULL fields. I solved this problem when I have added UPDATE statement, like this one, to the creation stage of the new object:

```
SET X1077_69_EDECESSOR = 0, X1077_70_EDECESSOR = 0, WHERE ID = :moversid
```

In this case new object creates with NULL fields and then they will be updated to 0 value.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you do not have a foreign key setup in the database, as insert 0 would fail such a constraint.  Odd that you have a not null constraint, but no foreign key constraint.  It would be best to fix your database, as it is improperly designed.

If you can't setup a null root that has a 0 id, then you could make the join columns insertable/updateable=false and define basic fields to write to the columns, then you would have control over their value in your model.  You would need to set the basic fields when the predecessor is set, and default them to 0, if no predecessor.